# Rendering partial and activating modal window onclick - any idea why it's so slow?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Basically on click, I'm rendering a specific partial window within a modal window (provided by Twitter Bootstrap). But, it's randomly very slow - any ideas why, or how to fix it? Here are the relevant code snippets:

view:

```
<% @utilities.each do |u| %>
<span class="util_click">
    <%= link_to u.name, { :controller => :users, :action => :show, :util_id => u.id, :rent_id => rent.id }, :remote => true %>
</span>
<% end %>

....

<div id="partialModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal Header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

    <div id="editUtil"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        ...
    </div>                          

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".util_click").click(function() {
    $('#partialModal').modal("show"); 
});
```

relevant part of controller:

```
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js {
          @rent = Rent.find(@current_user.id)
          @util_id = params[:util_id]
          @rent_id = params[:rent_id]
        }
    end
```

show.js.erb:

```
$("#editUtil").html('<%= escape_javascript(raw render :partial => "utilEdit", :locals => {:util => Utility.find(params[:util_id]), :rent_id => params[:rent_id]} ).html_safe%>');
```

And _utilEdit.html.erb is a form that iterates over a collection. Keeping in mind that I'm a rails dummy, anyone have any ideas for speeding up performance? It's the same in both development and production mode, btw.

Comment: Have you looked in your logs to see if there are any particularly slow queries in there?

Comment: Just checked. It looks like rendering show.js.erb consistently takes the most time.

Comment: Oh, nvm. I see the query that's really slowing it down is <%= BillOwed.where(:u_id => util.id, :r_id => coll.id)[0].price %> BillOwed has a lot of records, I'm not sure how to speed this query up.

Comment: Think about putting some `add_index` commands in a rails migration for that table. Have a look at this: http://tomafro.net/2009/08/using-indexes-in-rails-index-your-associations

Comment: I added indices and it's a little faster, but once in a while it just hangs and never finishes.